# How do I create menu links programmatically?

Tags: 8, navigation

I need to add some links to existing menu (or to new) programmatically in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to create a menu item automatically this can be placed in a [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.9.x) implementation in the .install file; it will run when the database is updated.

```php
/**
 * Put the following line on the top of the file containing the
 * following code.
/*
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

$items = [
  '1' => 'Menuitem 1',
  '2' => 'Menuitem 2',
  '3' => 'Menuitem 3'
];

foreach($items as $nid => $title) {
  $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
    'title' => $title,
    'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nid],
    'menu_name' => 'main',
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  ]);
  $menu_link->save();
}
```

You can also programmatically create an entire menu.

```php
$menu = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('menu')
  ->create([
    'id' => 'menu_test',
    'label' => 'Test menu',
    'description' => 'Description text',
  ]);
$menu->save();
```

Comment: I think that the correct solution should use the menu yamls

Comment: How would you add a menu link as a child to a parent link?

Comment: Note.  For external links, use the syntax 'link' => ['uri' => 'https://www.example.com']

Comment: As of 8.6 and 8.7, I ran into problems using "internal:/node/123". It seems to read 'internal' and flag the link for re-discovery. Instead, using "entity:node/123" seems to work as expected. That is what is stored in the DB when you create a link via menu UI as well.

Answer (score 12):

If you would like to create module-defined menu links, add something like this example to your *custom_module.links.menu.yml* file:

```
custom_module.admin_item_1:
  title: 'New Admin Item 1'
  parent: system.admin
  description: 'Description of link goes here.'
  route_name: view.some_view_id.page_1
```

`parent` (optional) is the `id` column of the parent in the `menu_tree` table, and `route_name` is Drupal's internal route ID for where you'd like the menu item to link to.  It's in the `menu_tree` table as `route_name`.

See [Providing module-defined menu links](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links) and [Add a menu link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-menu-link) for more details and options.

Comment: Menu yamls only help if you know in advance what menu items you want to create, Programmatic creation may be on node save.

Comment: How to add translatable menu item that way? Like one menu item, but in 3 languages (different menu item titles and paths).

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @skorzh answer and reply to the comment from @Matt, if you want to nest a menu item inside another you have to get the parent id and set it as 'parent'. As an example this code nests the item inside the top level using the variable `$top_level` below.

```
$menu_link_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content');

$my_menu = $menu_link_storage->loadByProperties(['menu_name' => 'my-menu-name']);

foreach ($my_menu as $menu_item) {
  $parent_id = $menu_item->getParentId();
  if (!empty($parent_id)) {
    $top_level = $parent_id;
    break;
  }
}

$menu_link_storage->create([
  'title' => 'My menu link title',
  'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/my/path'],
  'menu_name' => 'my-menu-name',
  'parent' => $top_level,
  'expanded' => TRUE,
  'weight' => 0,
])->save();
```

Comment: The parent ID is a concatenated string containing `menu_link_content:` and a menu item's UUID.  For example`$parent_id = 'menu_link_content:' . $menu_item->uuid();`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who want to create a menu link associated with a node, you should put the format below for the link URI

> entity:node/{node-id}

instead of

> internal:/node/{node-id}

For example:

```php
MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu Title',
  'link' => [
    'uri' => "entity:node/{$node_id}",
  ],  
  'menu_name' => $menu_name,
  'parent' => "$menu_name:",
])->save();
```